# Where are the other windows in Gimp?

Tags: image-editing

**(Edit: Fixed to be workable but still an open question - please see bottom)**

I've tried using both the official version from Gimp's website as well as the one from http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Photo_editing.html.

Both exhibit the same problem:  I can't locate any of the other windows like Layers or Toolbox.  The only window shown is the one displaying my image.  I've searched the interface for an option but can't find anything to reveal the hidden ones.

I'm sure it's not a bug and I'm just ignorant but can someone please tell me how to get the other windows to display?

Some further info:

- Both versions of the application showed some of the other, probably default, windows when I began using them.  However, upon subsequently opening the program, only the window with my image is displayed.
- I tried switching Gimp to Single-Window, and that helped once in lisanet.de's version.  But after I re-opened Gimp, all I see is this now (even if I toggle it on and off):

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Edit: In lisanet.de's version I just realized that "Hide Docks" was checked in Single-Window mode.  Oops!  Sorry about that.  However, I'd still like to know how to get the other windows to show up in non-Single-Window mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Window -> Dockable Dialogs` menu you should see a list of all of the possible windows you can show, such as Colors, Layers and so on. You can turn them on one by one and then re-arrange them into docks as before.

I remember that at some point there was an option to display the default docks but it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Thank you.  In regular gimp I see that option.  But I'm nearly 100% certain I checked that before and it didn't work.  However, the point is moot because for some strange reason, I can see the regular windows now when I open Gimp.  I have been re-opening and closing it for the last few hours and it wasn't working.  Anyway, I'll mark the answer as correct.  Thanks again.  Maybe I was experiencing a true bug then.